# Azure Service Bus vs RabbitMQ for Enterprise applications

Tags: rabbitmq, azureservicebus, servicebus, bitnami

I need to decide between Azure Service Bus and RabbitMQ (Deployed on Azure) for an enterprise level application and my major use will be of topics (with durable storage).
I see that service bus has more features as compared to RabbitMQ like Retries Count, TTL, sessions & transactions etc. But I am not sure which one is best for High availability, scalability, storage and throughput.
Service bus has some limits on store size (max 5 GB for non-partitioned queue and 80 GB for partitioned queue) and throughput of 2000 msgs/sec/queue. What if I need more then these limits in case of service bus?

The limits of RabbitMQ is not clear as it depends on the cluster. If anyone can help me in deciding which one would be the best in my case?

Comment: I found a blog talking about the cost comparison between Azure Service Bus and RabbitMQ on Azure VMs, you could refer to it [here](http://www.mariuszwojcik.com/blog/Cost-comparison-between-Azure-Service-Bus-Queues-and-RabbitMQ).

Comment: I have seen it @Bruce-MSFT . Cost is not a factor. I am confused about the performance and scalability of service bus.

Comment: Why don't you consider Amazon SQS which you can scale out? You can connect SQS to SNS and use as a topic for your case.

Comment: I've been a long time RMQ user. I just started to use AMB and I'm not overly impressed with the performance. But in all fairness, I haven't given AMB enough time to compare. I found this article about AMB performance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements

Comment: If your other infrastructures are heavily depends on Azure , I would like to recommend Azure SB. 
If you are planing( any probability) going out of Azure you may use RabbitMQ.

Comment: Costing may also be a consideration https://www.mariuszwojcik.com/cost-comparison-between-azure-service-bus-queues-and-rabbitmq/

Comment: If one wants developers to be able to have a local test environment, that is unfortunately [not available for Azure Service Bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033345/using-azure-service-bus-in-local). So that is one reason to choose something else like RabbitMQ

Answer (score 26):

My 2 cents - RabbitMQ with Docker and Kubernetes as part of your application infrastructure gives you portability. That is you can decide to move your app to a different cloud provider more easily than if you use Azure message bus.

Comment: This is not a comparison perse. Enterprises don't change cloud often. Question & answer don't match.

Comment: Actually you can use Azure Service Bus and stilll have the portability. The portability can come from the configuration. Using IaC tools like Terraform gives you the ability to replace the underlying service.

Comment: Using a messaging framework like NServiceBus or MassTransit that supports both RabbitMQ and Azure Service Bus (among other choices) will give you a very good level of "portability" as well as the ability to unit test the various parts of your system without the underlying broker: https://docs.particular.net/transports/rabbitmq/  https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus/

Comment: misleading - Azure service bus is not limited to Azure - it can be used from on prem DC or other cloud providers

Comment: @GregBala - Interesting, do you have any documentation to explain how you run Azure Service Bus on premise?

Comment: People used to be available to run Windows Azure Service Bus on-prem, but the installer was removed (in the past year, no more Windows Platform Installer) and the on-prem version is deprecated. That was probably made before the cloud-based services were a thing in Azure.

Comment: @RobertPerry I did not say you are "run" azure service bus" on prem, I said you can "use" it "from" on prem code. Aka Azure service bus gives you an HTTPS access